R command+F Mac (Sonoma)
So, I have been using R for several years (not R studio, the default R application from macOS), and one thing has always bothered me, but I have been tolerating:
When I type command+F to find something in my script, I am transferred to a popup search window and, from there, I can type whatever I am searching for. So far so good. But then, if I press "enter" or click "next" manually with my mouse, I am transferred from this popup window to the text editor. Therefore, if I were to type anything else (e.g., press "enter" to find the next word) I end up typing on the editor, not on the search window. This, therefore, makes it harder to conduct searches, as I must always go back to the search window and press "next" again manually:

Well, that is pretty bad, but somewhat tolerable. But ever since I have updated to Sonoma, whenever I type caps lock (to make all words uppercase), I get the blue symbol indicating that everything is in uppercase (so far so good). But then, if I type anything, I am transferred from the R script to the R console, and, as I type some more, I am transferred from the R console to the script back again! This, in my opinion, is unacceptable.
My questions are: 1) has any other user experienced any of these issues? 2) How do I fix them?
So far I have only experienced these bugs on R, not in other applications.
Here are some specifications about my R application:
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
[R.app GUI 1.79 (8238) aarch64-apple-darwin20]
And about the specifications of my operating system:
Chip Apple M1
Memory: 8GB
MacOS: Sonoma 14.4

For the first issue, you can find the next match with command-G rather than going to the find popup again. I cannot replicate the behavior you describe with caps lock. Tested with R 4.3.3 GUI 1.80 Big Sur ARM build (8340) If you want to report a bug, you can do so on the r-sig-mac mailing list: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac
